# PHP Soap Request headers not working correctly with a variable?

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap, php-curl

I've been trying to create a concatenated url to use in a `SOAPAction` POST using php curl.

I've encountered an intersting issue with the SOAP Api i'm trying to access.

If i use the httpheaders array as:

```
$header = array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IProductsService/getProduct"
);
```

I have no issues. It goes through and the response is exactly what i would expect.

However, if i use it like this:

```
$A = "ProductsService";
$B = "getProduct";
$soapAction = "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/I" . $A . "/" . $B;

$headerTest = array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    $soapAction
);
```

It doesn't work. (yes there is an I on the soap action i need to use) 
I've tried various different ways of doing this. With soap action in the array, without soap action in the array. Syntatically in PHP it IS correct. However i keep getting the response from the api stating `"ActionNotSupported"`. It says it cannot be processed due to a `contractFilter mismatch at the endpointDispatcher`.

Does anyone know why? And what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: A string is a string. It doesn't matter how you've put it together. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: That's what i thought. It shouldn't cause any issues. But it's honestly just the headers line that's causing problems in my curl. I'm just honestly not sure why :s